# Adaptive Meshrefinement NDSolve&FiniteElements

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, mesh

In a simple example I try to solve the heat equation using `NDSolve`   and `Method->"FiniteElement"`. I know that NDSolve gives the solution as an interpolationfunction inside an `ElementMesh`.

First the mesh is created

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
disc = ImplicitRegion[  x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && 0 <= z <= 1/10, {x, y , z}];
mesh = DiscretizeRegion[disc, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Volume" -> Pi/10}];
MeshCells[mesh, 3] // Length  (*36279*)
```

The mesh has around 36000 elements.

Simulation inside this mesh

```
U = NDSolveValue[{ 0 ==    Laplacian[u[ x, y, z ] , {x, y, z }]+ 50NeumannValue[1,  x >= 0 && y >= 0 && z == 1/10     ]-  1     NeumannValue[u[ x, y, z] - 20, z == 1/10] },u, 
Element[{x, y, z }, mesh ] , Method -> "FiniteElement"] 
DensityPlot[U[x, y, 1/10],Element[{x, y}, ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 1, {x, y}]],ColorFunction -> (ColorData["TemperatureMap"][#1] &),MaxRecursion -> 4]
```

gives a feasible solution

[image]

with considerably refined mesh

```
U["ElementMesh"]
(*TetrahedronElement["<" 160748 ">"]*)
```

consisting of now 160748 elements, that means **440% increase of meshsize**!

My question:
Is it possible to keep the initial mesh `mesh` unchanged(fixed) by NDSolve?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `ToElementMesh` versus `DiscretizeRegion` and look at the "Wireframe", then you will see that your mesh looks pretty ugly.

```
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image: Initial Discretized Region]

You can make a prettier mesh by starting with a geometry that has more cube-like aspect ratio and then scale the z-coordinate and remesh as shown below:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
(* Stretch Disc Region for better aspect ratio *)
disc = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && 0 <= z <= 1, {x, y, z}];
mesh0 = ToElementMesh[disc]
mesh0["Wireframe"]
(* Scale z-coords and create new ElementMesh *)
crd = mesh0["Coordinates"];
crd[[All, 3]] = crd[[All, 3]]/10;
mesh = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> crd, 
   "MeshElements" -> mesh0["MeshElements"], 
   "BoundaryElements" -> mesh0["BoundaryElements"], 
   "PointElements" -> mesh0["PointElements"]];
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image: ToElementMesh Approach]

Now, you can perform your `NDSolveValue` in the following way and it should default to the FEM method.

```
U = NDSolveValue[{-Laplacian[
      u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == +50 NeumannValue[1, 
       x >= 0 && y >= 0 && z == 1/10] - 
     1 NeumannValue[u[x, y, z] - 20, z == 1/10]}, u, 
  Element[{x, y, z}, mesh]]
DensityPlot[U[x, y, 1/10], 
 Element[{x, y}, ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 1, {x, y}]], 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["TemperatureMap"][#1] &)]
```

[image: More Uniform Mesh]

Now, you can verify that the solution required about 10x fewer elements than the original approach.

```
U["ElementMesh"]
(* ElementMesh[{{-1., 1.}, {-1., 1.}, {0., 
   0.1}}, {TetrahedronElement["<" 16103 ">"]}] *)
```

## Speed Improvement

In 3D problems, it is often useful to extract boundary meshes for visualizations. Below, I show a method to extract the top surface for the `DensityPlot`.  The overhead in extracting the top surface is dwarfed by the efficiency gains in the `DensityPlot` function.  On my machine, the following code was 350x faster than the code in the OP an 16.7x faster than the code above.

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 (* Stretch Disc Region for better aspect ratio *)
 disc = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && 0 <= z <= 1, {x, y, z}];
 mesh0 = ToElementMesh[disc];
 (* Scale z-coords and create new ElementMesh *)
 crd = mesh0["Coordinates"];
 crd[[All, 3]] = crd[[All, 3]]/10;
 mesh = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> crd, 
   "MeshElements" -> mesh0["MeshElements"], 
   "BoundaryElements" -> mesh0["BoundaryElements"], 
   "PointElements" -> mesh0["PointElements"]];
 U = NDSolveValue[{-Laplacian[
       u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == +50 NeumannValue[1, 
        x >= 0 && y >= 0 && z == 1/10] - 
      1 NeumannValue[u[x, y, z] - 20, z == 1/10]}, u, 
   Element[{x, y, z}, mesh]];
 (* Extract Top Surface as 2D Mesh *)
 (* Select Top Surface by Normal *)
 mask = (0.9999 < -{0, 0, 1}.#) & /@ mesh0["BoundaryNormals"][[1]];
 topelmi = 
  Pick[ElementIncidents[mesh0["BoundaryElements"]][[1]], mask];
 (* Extract unique incidents from top surface *)
 unique = DeleteDuplicates@Flatten[topelmi];
 (* Create an associate to renumber connectivity *)
 crddict = AssociationThread[unique -> Range@Length@unique];
 crd2d = mesh0["Coordinates"][[All, 1 ;; 2]];
 crd2dtop = crd2d[[unique]];
 newincidents = MapAt[crddict, topelmi, {All, All}];
 mesh2d = 
  ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> crd2dtop, 
   "MeshElements" -> {TriangleElement[newincidents]}];
 (* Plot using new 2D mesh *)
 DensityPlot[U[x, y, 1/10], {x, y} \[Element] mesh2d, 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["TemperatureMap"][#1] &)]
 ]
```

[image: Using Boundary Surface For Plotting]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I observed the same effect, using `MeshTools` to create easy structured `mesh` (as you did) , that the mesh keeps unchanged, as desired.

Comment: Technically, my mesh is unstructured.  On my machine, the number of mesh elements changes each time I mesh.  Unstructured meshers have an easier time with domains with aspect ratios near unity.  Structured or extruded meshes are the way to go for this geometry.  If I saw support for a wedge element, I probably would have extruded a `Disk`.  Also, I added a section to speed up the `DensityPlot` that you may be interested in since plotting seems to be the throughput limiter.

Comment: Thanks again, very interesting! Your basic trick meshing well proportioned geometries and scale the mesh afterwards is what I was looking for.  I've to elaborate your new remarks...

Comment: @TimLaska is Adaptive Meshrefinement now supported in Mma 12.2?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM Although the title contains the term adaptive mesh refinement, it really is not about adaptive mesh refinement in the sense you are thinking. But to answer your question, no adaptive mesh refinement is not a feature of 12.3. In a recent comment from user21, the priority is on structural mechanics (a wide and deep field) and not on meshing (also a wide and deep field). I would not expect adaptive mesh refinement to be available in the near term.